# Convert into PLSQL block statement for mulitple ID

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Here is the PL/SQL block statement which run for 1 sub_id :-

```
declare
 v_sub   table_b%rowtype;
 v_res      varchar2(10);
begin
 FOR i in (select distinct b.sid from table_a a, table_b b where a.sub_id = 11)
 LOOP
  select * into v_sub from table_b where sid = i.sid;

  ---- SP call (mention default name of stored procedure)
  user.pkg.sp(p_sub => v_sub, p_res => v_res);

  insert into table_c
  (11,
   i.sid,
   v_res,
   sysdate);
  commit;
 end loop;
end;
```

The above block execute for 1 sub_id = 11 but in actual there are 10 sub_id which should execute at one time when PL/SQL block execute. 
`ID's are - 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 19, 21, 23, 27, 30`

So I want to convert above PL/SQL block statement so that for all sub_id PL/SQL execute at one time and the same PL/SQL block will run in shell script also.

Comment: @Tejash has posted the same immediate solution I was thinking of.  But there is another question.  Where do those input values come from?  Are they ever subject to change?  The answers to those questions might suggest a better, more intelligent and self-adapting solution.

Comment: @EdStevens These ID's are value of sub_id of table_a. So i need to take few of them.

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you saying they are values from a column in some table, but you don't need _all_ of the values in that table?  If so, how do you determine which ones you need? How do you determine which ones you _do not_ need?  I'm asking, because I belive there might be a way to write this so that you are not dependent on a hard-coded list that might be subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` in for loop and use the loop variable accordingly.

```
declare
 v_sub_id   table_b.sid%type;
 v_res      varchar2(10);
begin
 FOR i in (select distinct sub_id from table_a where sub_id IN (7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 19, 21, 23, 27, 30))
   -- change here in WHERE condition
 LOOP
  select * into v_sub_id from table_b where sid = i.sub_id;

  ---- SP call (mention default name of stored procedure)
  user.pkg.sp(p_sub_id => v_sub_id, p_res => v_res);

  insert into table_c VALUES -- values keyword was missing in your query
  (i.sub_id, -- change here
   i.sub_id,
   v_res,
   sysdate);
  commit;
 end loop;
end;
```

Required changes are mentioned in the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

select distinct b.sid from table_a a, table_b b where a.sub_id = 11
you dont connect the two tables
insert into table_c
  (11,
   i.sid,
   v_res,
   sysdate);
you insert one and the same value 11.problem may be here

Comment: But when i am executing for 1 sid then it is executing and DML operation perform successfully.